# Rerender full page using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, submit

I am more backednd developer and sometimes ui things confuding me.

I have html form

```
<form action="getNewPage">
  ...
  <input type="submit'>
</form>
```

`getNewPage` returns  html page
when I click on submit

Then page reloads and html returned from `getNewPage` renders on this page.

How can I achieve it using ajax?
Is it possible?

### P.S.

I just want to know

Comment: of course it's possible. Shouldn't have any trouble finding tutorials for submitting from with ajax

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery (the JavaScript framework) for it.
Example:

```
// #theForm - form id
$.get('server.php?' + $('#theForm').serialize());
$.post('server.php', $('#theForm').serialize());
```

Comment: it is just request. As I understand page doesn't reload

Comment: It is just a example. You can add the function which will be called after server response.
Take a look into documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

`$.post('server.php', $('#theForm').serialize(), function(data){
    // You can do what you want (update content in the page or just reload page or ...)
});`

Comment: The good practice is to change only a part of page instead of whole page after the ajax request. Because your action practically always impacts only to small piece of the page content. For content update you can use the jQuery [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function. If it is neccessary to update all content in the page after ajax request, then is better to reload (refresh) page.

Comment: At this case js libraries and css  will be load?

Comment: It is very dependent on what you changing. You should manually bind the all custom functions to the element events after the creation of it in the HTML DOM (page content).